# Jupyter Notebook doesn't see the installed libraries

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I searched for this question, but their solution did not help. Problem - I installed the libraries, but jupyter notebook doesn't see them, not all of them, some of them I installed and it imports them perfectly. Problems with tensorflow and keras

```
import tensorflow
import keras
```

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last) ipython-input-9-c79ed1f6e965 in module

```
----> 1 import tensorflow

      2 import keras
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Python version 3.8.0

I tried installing in the terminal, but the result is the same

[img installed tensorflow in jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m9q7.png)

[img installed keras](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH7oN.png)

Comment: have you installed your libraries in conda environment(which is used bt JUpyter Notebook)

Comment: In my experience, (ana)conda is a lot better at managing tensorflow/jupyter, especially on windows. I suggest using conda to manage environments and packages when working with machine learning tools.

Comment: and just python won't do? Do you need conda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, tensorflow<2 only works with python 3.6.* 64 bit. And it doesn't work with python 3.8.

keras need tensorflow or theano as backend, and when you don't have tensorflow or theano, keras doesn't work too.
You need to uninstall python 3.8 and install python 3.6.* and try to install tensorflow and then keras with this command in terminal or cmd

'pip install tensorflow'
'pip install keras'

(You also can install theano instead of tensorflow, it works with python 3.8 and then install keras.
Or clarify the version of tensorflow that is compatible with python 3.8, when you are installing tensorflow)

Comment: No, this is not true, TensorFlow 2.2 supports Python 3.8

Comment: I workd with tensorflow 1.15 and I found that it does work with python 3.8. Then I think it is better you clarify version of tensorflow when you want to install it, I used this command, ' pip install tensorflow==1.15' you can change the version as you want

Comment: This last comment now contradicts your answer.

Comment: I answered as I experienced myself, I edited my answer